# joomla Database connection error (2) after fix configuration.php

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, mysqli

I installed joomla on server and it worked properly about two days ago.
I do this three job:

1. clean trash folder in cpanel
2. delete error_log in root folder
3. upload google webmaster authentication file .

These 3 jobs don't have any logical relevance to this problem but afterwards I see this error :

> Database connection error (2): Could not connect to MySQL [this
>   website](http://rah-pooyan.ir/)

I tried to fix configuration.php problems but there isn't any issues.
I changed user of db with all Privilege  and apply changes to this file.
I checked all db tables.
I disabled .htaccess and re enable that.
but I cant fix this problem...

Comment: is your configuration.php in the root? when you say 'I changed user of db with all Privilege and apply changes to this file' did you change the creditentials or just created a new user?

Comment: @ArturPeniche yes. configuration.php is in root folder. I creat a new user,then I Add this User To Database with all Privilege. then update configuration.php with this new user parameters .

Answer (score 0):

My Two bets are:

1. Permissions: change the configuration.php file to 644 or to something you feel correct
2. DB Password expired : I don't know how you're accessing the server but try to renew the password

Comment: does database have different password ? I changed user password and I update configuration.php . if these are equal , I did this and it couldn't solve my problem.

Comment: when you said you changed the admin user did you do doing the method 2? https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_recover_or_reset_your_admin_password%3F

Comment: i never changed admin user. just I add new DB user to DBS.   I recovered server backup to fix this issue. it was very deep problem.

Comment: well iam glad you fixed the problem